# Android: Limit webview to a number of URLs

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

In my application, I want to limit the URL to a number of domains. For example, if I want to limit it to **one** domain, this works:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("stackoverflow.com")) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

So how do I alter this line:

```
if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("stackoverflow.com"))
```

To whitelist a number of URLs, like:

```
stackoverflow.com
stackexchange.com
google.com
```

Comment: I think add all urls in ArrayList and use `if(urlList.contains(Uri.parse(url).getHost())){return false}else{//open page}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fastest way is to keep a list of your allowed hosts.

```java
List<String> allowedHosts = Arrays.asList("stackoverflow.com", "stackexchange.com", "google.com");

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
    if (allowedHosts.contains(host) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```